# Ways to start a program at the same time as cmd

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I'm in a bit of a quandary: when I want to start a program at the same time as another program, my normal MO is to make a batch file that goes something like this:

```
@ echo off
start exe1.exe
start exe2.exe
exit
```

I compile the batch file, then rename the original program to `exe1.exe` and the (compiled) batch file to the name of the original program (to keep shortcuts working). Unfortunately, I now need to start a program at the same time as cmd. Modifying cmd itself seems to be out of the question, and I don't want to get bogged down writing a multi-threaded program to monitor currently running processes. Anybody have some tips? I was thinking of using the task scheduler, but I'm not sure what do do with it... Thanks! I'm using Win 7 and I don't really want more 3rd-party software on here than I need....

Note: This can't just be a program that starts cmd and then another program. EVERY TIME cmd opens, this program needs to open too. Even going into `C:\Windows\System32` and MANUALLY running it should result in my other program being run.

Comment: Maybe you could leave some context as to why you would like to do what  you want to do.  Sometimes, there is more than one way to something, and sometimes there is not.  But given the amount of people out there with great ideas, it would be prudent to include some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CMD.EXE help:

```
CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

...
/D      Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry (see below)
...

If /D was NOT specified on the command line, then when CMD.EXE starts, it
looks for the following REG_SZ/REG_EXPAND_SZ registry variables, and if
either or both are present, they are executed first.

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

        and/or

    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

So you should be able to create the registry entry with a command to start your program.

Comment: Agh! Didn't fully read this answer, so I posted my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try using Task Scheduler to achieve this. The steps are given below.

Open Task Scheduler > Actions tab > Create Task > Name the Task > Goto Triggeres tab > click on New > select "On an Event" from the Log drop down > Enter the Source and Event ID of cmd, when it is opened > Goto Action tab > Enter the path of the other program that you want to start.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Huh. This doesn't seem to be working. The paths are all spelled correctly, and I think I set up the events right...

Comment: @Vembu I don't see how this would work, because opening cmd.exe doesn't get logged as far as I can see, so there is no eventID to input in the task. `Get-EventLog application -newest 5 | Format-list`, `Get-EventLog system -newest 5 | Format-list`. The OP could create his own event, but that doesn't help since he doesn't want to run cmd.exe from a batch script, or altered shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tampering with `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe` is dangerous. 
Do you feel comfortable with modifying the shortcut(s) that you use to run `cmd`?

If you type `cmd /?`, you’ll get a usage message that includes:

```
CMD [other options …] [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below)
```

(and further down it talks about how `/S`
modifies the interpretation of quotes in the command string).

So, if you create a shortcut whose Target box says something like

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k "%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"
```

then, every time you invoke that shortcut, it will start a Command Prompt,
and the `cmd` will start a WordPad process
(and then issue a prompt, and read commands from the terminal, as usual). 
As in your question,
you may need to include `start` in the command string after `cmd.exe /k`.

Comment: Right, but this program needs to start with CMD all of the time. In other words, even if I don't get to choose HOW cmd is opened, I would like this program to open with it. Unless you know how to modify literally EVERY method of opening the program (including GOING to `System32` and double-clicking), I can't really use this.

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand the question, but i just texted this as a standard batch file (not compiled) and it worked.

`@ echo off
start exe1.exe
start cmd
exit`

Which opened a new cmd window at the same time as my test application.  (I used something different than exe1.exe).

A cmd shell can open a new cmd shell.

Comment: Right, but what if I start up cmd by going into `System32` and clicking on it? Or using another programming language to run the command `start`? Or hitting CTRL + R and putting in "cmd"? Or just opening up the start menu and typing it in? All of these are ways to start cmd, but I want my program to run no matter which one I choose. Check out @dbenham 's solution (which I ended up using).